# probability question finding number of balls in jar

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

[image]

What i think breakdown is not possible as the we are on profit side while considering the three cases.
Or we have to consider 1 random trial ?

can you please help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected revenue from a draw is
$$
0.4(50)+0.5x+0.1(90)=0.5x+29
$$
as we will get $50$ dollars for $40$ percent of the time $90$ dollars for $10$ percent of the time and unknown amount $x$ for $50$ percent of the time (corresponding to drawing a blue marble).

We will break even if the expected revenue is at least the cost of entry i.e.
$$
0.5x+29\geq 46
$$

Comment: are u sure this is correct or it should be 46*3 at the right ?

Answer (score 1):

Outline/hint: Let $x$ be the unknown payout for a blue marble.

Then your expected value of drawing a marble (inclusive of the $\$46$ you pay for the game) is $.4\cdot(50)+.5x+.1\cdot(90)-46$